# Fixing error: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer

I'm using MERN and multer to post and get images and data. I have no issues accomplishing this within Postman, but when I run the code it compiles the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at router.post (...routes\property.js:42:34)
```

**Code:**

```
router.post('/add', upload.single('propertyImage'), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file)
  const propertyImage = req.file.path;
```

I'm assuming that my `req` call is wrong? I've attempted to change the `req` to `req.file` and `req.body.propertyImage` but that results in a different error entirely or the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what's in the log?

Comment: can you please console req.body

Comment: Did you try `req.propertyImage` and send the file input name as propertyImage? And also make sure you're using `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya sure. The req.body logs the following:
`propertyImage: {}`

Comment: @KeitelDOG I gave that a shot and still no go. Getting the req.body I mentioned in an earlier comment, and a catch error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add

```
enctype = "multipart/form-data"
```

in the form tag of your html

something like

```
  form(method='POST', action='/add', enctype = "multipart/form-data")
```

reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer (see the Basic Usage)

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at router.post (...routes\property.js:42:34)
```

is saying that no file has been able to be decoded by the the server. You have to make sure of 2 things:

1. you really upload a file correctly
2. You use correct Middleware in Express to decode the file

Let's dive inside of it.

PART 1 (CLIENT) - Make sure you use the upload the file correctly. Let's say you use `upload.single('propertyImage')`, then your file input must be named `propertyImage` too, so that Multer know how to decode the `multipart/form-data` request and separate the file from the rest of the input, because the file and inputs are merged in a special way that only special decoders like Multer can extract.

You can use the `multipart/form-data` content type. Example with Axios:

```
var payload = {
  input1: 'value1',
  propertyImage: file, // file must be a file object
};

var formData = new FormData();

for (let key in payload ) {
  formData.append(key, payload[key]);
}

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/add',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  data: formData,
})
```

PART 2 (SERVER) - Use the decoder for parsing the inputs:

```
const app = express();
// Middlewares
...
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));// put true for nested objects/arrays inputs
...
```

Check your Multer setup:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 3500;

const entityStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'public/images');// check for correct permission
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const name = 'file-' + Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname;
    cb(null,  name);
  }
});

const upload = multer({storage: entityStorage});
```

Now you should be able to get the file as:

```
router.post('/add', upload.single('propertyImage'), (req, res, next) => {
  // log the file object, file is default property name
  console.log(req.file)

  // rest of the inputs
  console.log(req.file)


  return; //cancel it
}
```